# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't loop over the response from this http call. For whatever reason it's complaining that the type of `data` is an object, but when I console log it I can an array like I expect.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

promises.push(Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.post(`items/event/${this.event.auction_code}`, body.toString(), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded' ),
    }).subscribe(data => {
       var classifiedData;
       data.forEach((item)=>{
          classifiedData.push(new Item(item));
       });
       observer.next(data);
       observer.complete();
    },error => {
       observer.throw(error);
    });
}));
...
Observable.forkJoin(promises).subscribe(results => {
   results.forEach((result,i)=>{
      data.content.template[i].data = result;
   });
});
```

**Edit:**

Console.log shows me this

[image]

**Edit: 2**

I also have an interceptor setup, could this be causing it?

```
@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const duplicate = req.clone({
      url: `${environment.apiUrl}/${req.url}`,
      params: req.params.set('key', environment.apiKey)
    });
    return next.handle(duplicate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems not to be an array as you expect. What does `console.log(data)` print?

Comment: I still get `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.`. Like I mentioned, console logging out `data` shows an array in the console.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot of what I see in the console

Comment: Jordan, if only typo question consider to delete it.

Comment: So I'm actually wondering how Visual Studio and the CLI know that the data coming back from that endpoint is not an array? Because when I look at the actual data from the server it looks to be a proper array

Comment: I added an interceptor I have set up, is there something I'm doing there that may be throwing this off?

Comment: Hmm, is this error on typescript or on transpiled javascript? If it's on typescript, try `this.http.post<any[]>('...`

Comment: That works, thanks, what is that btw?

Comment: Angular's HttpClient doesn't know what it is after parsing it from JSON so it assumes `Object`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It requires you to give it an explicit type for the request like so:

```
this.http.post<any[]>('...
```

According to [Angular HttpClient Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http), `HttpClient` doesn't know what it is after parsing it from JSON so it assumes `Object` as the type of response, so typescript complains about that.

Answer (score 1):

Object may be missing explicit array syntax. For instance if error is on this line

`this.subscriptions.forEach(...);`

Check where "subscriptions" is defined

**Before**

`private subscriptions: Subscription;`

**After**

`private subscriptions: Subscription[];`